# Cannot load CSS file from index.html

Tags: html, css, reactjs, webpack

I understand that is was a frequently asked question. I looked at many other topics on stack overflow about it and I still don't know what the issue is? Some are saying it's because it's reading the file type as a `text/html MIME` type however I declared in my index.html it as `text/css` and it's still throwing me an error in the console.

And when i change it to text/html in my index file, the error in the console goes away but my styles won't load at all on my page even though the path is correct?

Error i get in console: `localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:1234/assets/css/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

I've been stuck trying to figure this out for past 2 hours I think it's something small I'm missing.

Here is my project structure:

**INDEX.HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/styles.css">
    <title>Portfolio Application</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS Library -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

**Webpack.config file**

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: __dirname + "/src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/public",
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    query: {
                        presets: ['env', 'react', 'stage-0']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './public/index.html'
        })
    ]
}
```

Server file (Main.js)

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const port = 8010;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization');
    next();
});

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + "/../public"));

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`app is listening in on port ${port}`);
});
```

Folder structure:

- root
- public (folder)
  - assets
  - fonts
  - images
  - bundle.js
  - index.html
- server (folder)
  - main.js
- src (folder)
  - common (folder)
  - components (folder)
  - index.js
  - routes.js
- package.json
- webpack.config.js

Comment: what does `http://localhost:1234/assets/css/styles.css` have when you visit it in your browser?

Comment: Check the network tab in your browser inspector. Check the response for the request for the styles.css file. The MIME type that your server is returning is wrong probably. What is your server type? How is this file returned from the server?

Comment: Silly mistake. when i enter http://localhost:1234/public/assets/css/styles.css loads the stylesheet. However, I thought on my server when i serve static files I wouldn't need to put in public? Uploading my server example. Server is returning it as a stylesheet but it was getting canceled upon request.

Comment: According to the error message, index.html tries to load __http://localhost:1234/assets/css/styles.css__, not __http://localhost:1234/public/assets/css/styles.css__. So where is the css file really? And where is the index.html file?

Comment: I sent the folder architecture. Sorry i didn't know how to make a folder structure on SO so i just used unordered lists

Comment: If the css/ folder is in a subfolder of public/ (where index.html is) you should write `"assets/css/styles.css"` from within index.html, because the version with `../` wouldn't work. But then you would have got a 404 error (file not found) instead of what happens now.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help. One more question. on my server whats the purpose of express.static? I understand the context of where thats where public assets go but what I don't understand is does that have anything to do with how I call my static files if I alter the code?